# Difference between 'git push -f' and 'deleting remote branch and push again'

Tags: git

When I found my <del>wrong</del> mistakes at remote branch, I always delete this, squash locally and push again. Because I heard 'git push -f' was dangerous. However I noticed push result showing after git fetch is some thing like below.

new BRANCH_NAME "(force)"

My workflow deleting and pushing again is correct? What is different between the way and 'push -f'?

Comment: Is your remote repo contributed to by other developers?

Comment: What means "found my wrong at remote branch"?

Comment: @bcmcfc Yes and I had same such workflow at contributed and solo repo.

Comment: @gipi I would like to express "I pushed a commit including small mistakes something like typo" or "I pushed some commits but it should be squashed".

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Functionally, deleting and pushing again is *at least as dangerous* as `git push -f`.

However, deleting and pushing again is actually worse than `git -f push` for a very specific reason:

At least with `git -f push`, the **replacement is atomic**.

Albeit, this isn't a big deal when you're working solo.

1. When you use `git -f push`, you're told exactly what replacement took
   place in the resulting message: `X...Y branch ->
   branch (forced update)`.  From there, you can make sure `X` is really what were meaning to blow away.
2. When you do `git push origin :branch && git push origin branch`, you can't really tell what you deleted if you aren't absolutely the only person possibly pushing to `branch`.

Comment: Thanks for your reply! Your answer is very easy to understand ;) I will stop using "deleting and pushing again".

Answer (score 5):

No, deleting the remote branch first is not going to make it safer or anything.

The reason forced push is dangerous is due to workflow reason, not technical reasons. If someone pulled your erroneous branch, then you force push the correct change set on the branch, that may cause havoc on their history and on any changes they made on top of the branch because their pulls will no longer be fast forward (unless they fix their erroneous branch with force pull or if they rebase their changes), which could mean that they might reintroduce the erroneous changes again. In a team with just one committers, this usually won't be much of an issue, with larger projects, with lots of committers and lots of watchers, then the likelihood of problem much larger because it may not be just one or two person who've downloaded the erroneous branch.

Comment: @Sea-Mountain IOW, if you are the ONLY person using the repo, then you can go with either of the workflows that you are comfortable with.

Comment: Thank you answering me! I'm glad to hear clear answer like "It is due to workflow reason, not technical" so I could understand. I'm be careful about such workflow :)